# CKEditor Insert HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

1. I have a data from database.
2. In my js file, I would like to change my CKEditor text editor's value.
3. My value is raw html.
4. I want this raw value to be written on an empty CKEditor text editor.

I tried these but got an undefined function error all the time :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorID.insertHtml( '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>' );
CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorID.setData( '<p>This is the editor data.</p>' );
```

I tried this too but still undefined function error :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.YOUREDITORID.updateElement();
alert( document.getElementById( 'YOUREDITORID' ).value );
```

Instead of myEditorID i tried 'editor', 'editor1', 'editor2' but still doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

---Update---

This is the html of my ckeditor text editor :

```
<textarea id="myEditorID" name="myEditor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var myEditor = $('#myEditorID');
        myEditor.ckeditor({ 
        height: 200, 
        extraPlugins: 'charcount', 
        maxLength: 2000, 
        toolbar: 'TinyBare', 
        toolbar_TinyBare: [
             ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
             ['Undo','Redo'],['Cut','Copy','Paste'],
             ['NumberedList','BulletedList','Table'],['CharCount']
        ] 
        }).ckeditor().editor.on('key', function(obj) {
            if (obj.data.keyCode === 8 || obj.data.keyCode === 46) {
                return true;
            }
            if (myEditor.ckeditor().editor.document.getBody().getText().length >= 2000) {
                alert('You have reached the maximum char length');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to run with a debugger to see what is undefined.

Comment: does your length restriction work? if you hit 2000 characters do you get this message? `You have reached the maximum char length`

Comment: Your variable scoping seems... interesting. Where did you try `insertHtml()`? I don't see it in your example. Or is it in the console? Also, what is undefined; `CKEDITOR` or `CKEDITOR.instances` or `CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorID`? I'd refactor that code to be a little more easier on the eyes before doing anything else.

Comment: I called it as an object in my customized js file with CKEDITOR.document.getById('blablaID') and now working on it.

Comment: @Nenotlep when i debug it says CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorID is undefined function. Having a problem because of CKeditor character counter plugin.

Comment: This might sound like a silly question but are you sure you are calling it after the instance is ready?

Comment: @Nenotlep its not silly, thank you for your participation. But yes i called it after the instance is ready. I wish I could share my code with jsfiddle etc. but it's quite long. Now i'm trying another plugin, but let you know what's gonna happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Instead of myEditorID i tried 'editor', 'editor1', 'editor2' but still
>   doesn't work for me.

You need to look at the HTML of your page and see what the ID field is for your editor. It will be something like this

```
<textarea id="my_editor"></textarea>
```

That id attribute is what needs to go in here

```
CKEDITOR.instances.my_editor.insertHtml('<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>');
```

Comment: I don't know why people is voting down, but i already have written exactly what you said. Still not working, i'm going to solve this out and write down the answer.

Comment: it seems that insertHtml is not available anymore

Comment: I'm using ckeditor 4.10 (the latest 4.x release as of 8/9/2018) and it DOES have insertHtml()...

Comment: @VernJensen this question is over 3 years old so I assume they added it at some point

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CKeditor like

```
<textarea id="user_body"></textarea>
```

To insert data, Please use the following line of Code

```
CKEDITOR.instances["user_body"].insertHtml('');
```

Hope it will work for you. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML

```html
<textarea name="contenteditor" id="contenteditor" style="margin:0px 10px;">
</textarea>
```

In your JavaScript (JQuery)

```js
$(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace('contenteditor');

    //Your data
    var yourData = '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>';

    //insert your data in the editor
    $("#contenteditor").val(yourData);
})
```