# how to pass html to CKEditor textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Please help, im buliding a forum, and im im using CKEditor as my wysiwyg. I wanna implement the reply system, so that when a user replies, there is some predefined markup so that others will know its a reply. That means i have to pass the markup to the textarea, then the user can put whatever reply he has and save.

Right now i cannot pass the predefined html that will style the reply. I tried a lot of things including `setdata()` but it seems to return plain text.

here is my code

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData( "<div style = font-size:11px; background: #e3e3e3;padding:5px;><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?> <i class='fa fa-reply' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo $post->username; ?></b></div" );
```

Does anyone know of a suitable method? or solution?
thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEditor Insert HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800375/ckeditor-insert-html)

Comment: The documentation is your friend: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around is to capture an instance of the CKEditor and implementing the **insertHtml** function

**If you are trying to use it inside a plugin:**

```
var editor;
// In your plugin.js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME', {
    init: function(edtr){
        editor = edtr;
        // YOUR OTHER CODE
    }
});
```

**If you are doing something using the CKEditors config.js :**

```
var editor;
// In your config.js
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (event) {
    editor = event.editor;
    // YOUR OTHER CODE 
});
```

After that, all you do is :

```
editor.insertHtml("<div>Your-Custom-HTML</div>");
```

Or you can directly do something as shown [here](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/heres-how-insert-text-and-tags-cursor).

There are different ways of doing the same thing, based on your circumstances and requirements.