# How can I store raw html with ckeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I just integrate CKEditor 4 in my web, the problem is when I paste HTML code into edit area like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGL0Y.png)

the value I got is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTVjq.png)
So, Is there a way I can store Raw Html like the first picture?

UPDATE: I want CKEditor know when I paste HTML Code, Output HTML also is raw HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEditor Insert HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800375/ckeditor-insert-html)

Comment: I'm reading that topic

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I add these lines to my config.js

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;

config.fullPage = true;

config.basicEntities = false;
```

It solved the problem